# Get newest record per group from subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I would like to get the latest record based on `date` for each `email` from my query.

This query produces multiple records for each email. Let's call this output, table `C`.

My question is: How to filter from the alias table `C` only the most recent record.

```
+-------------------+-----+------------+
| email             | id  | date       |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
| hello@example.com | 123 | 2020-06-21 |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
| hello@example.com | 123 | 2020-06-15 |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
```

Desired result is:

```
+-------------------+-----+------------+
| email             | id  | date       |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
| hello@example.com | 123 | 2020-06-21 |
+-------------------+-----+------------+
```

My starting query (that produces multiple email records) is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Email,
    ID,
    Date
FROM [TABLE_A] AS a    
LEFT JOIN (
    select *
    from [TABLE_B]
    where ID = '123'
) AS b
ON a.Email = b.Key
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT c.Email, c.ID, c.Date
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Email,
        ID,
        Date
    FROM [TABLE_A] AS a   
    LEFT JOIN (
        select *
        from [TABLE_B]
        where ID = '123'
    ) AS b ON a.Email = b.Key   
) AS c    
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Email, max(Date) as MaxDate
    FROM c
    GROUP BY Email
) tm on c.Email = tm.Email and c.Date = tm.Date
```

Looks like SQL cannot 'see' table C as I am getting an error:

> invalid object name

Comment: Does `ID` stay constant as shown in your sample data? Or should it in fact change per record?

Comment: it will stay the same

Comment: So all you want then is `SELECT Email, ID, max(Date) FROM [TABLE_A] group by Email, ID`

Comment: Ah no. My initial query is the one from where I require the latest (`email`) records. So from that query, I would like filter/select only the most recent records based on `date`

Comment: Then please update your question with enough sample data and expected results to explain what you mean, because the query I showed gives what you are asking.

Comment: @DaleK Correction: When using your suggestion, I indeed get desired result. However, Im doing:  SELECT Email, ID, max(Date) FROM [TABLE_C] group by Email, ID

Comment: My comment still stands, you need to clarify your question, because its unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WITH TIES` in concert with `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By Id Order By [Date] Desc)
```